# How do I get rid of the Expected Identifier Error?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to c and am doing the cs50 course through Harvard. I'm working on Problem Set 1, and the only error in my code right now is the "expected identifier or ")", which I have no idea what I'm supposed to do for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

{
    int get_positive_int(void);

    int main(void);
    {
        int i = get_positive_int();
        printf("%i\n", I);
    }

    // prompt user for positive integer
    int get_positive_int(void)
    {
        int n;
        do
        {
            int n = get_int("Positive Number: \n");
        }
        while (n<1);
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the open brace mean before the declaration {
int get_positive_int(void);? And why is there a semicolon after main int main(void);?

Comment: Why do you have braces around your functions?

Comment: There is a pair of curly brackets `{ }` (the first and last in the code) grouping the entire code into a block that should not be there. Remove them. (Proper indentation of the code makes it easier to detect this kind of error).

Comment: @Areesh Sobhani Try at first to write the "hello world" program.

Comment: You'll also need to remove the semi-colon in `int main(void);`

Comment: What is the vote down for? The question is properly presented, except it omits the full text of the message (showing the line number). But the full source code is provided, and the error is easily reproduced. Further, this is a valid, non-trivial question: The compiler message is wrong. At that point in the file, there should be a *function-definition* or a *declaration* according to the C grammar. Although those could start with an identifier in old C grammar, these days we generally expect a keyword first, such as `int` or `extern`. So the confusing compiler message is worth asking about.